# Doubt on proof of fundamental theorem of arithmetic by strong induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, induction

I was reading  through a proof by strong induction of the FTA and I am not sure of a passage:

We must prove that for every integer higher of equal then $2$, this can be written as the product of one or many primes.

Base: $2$ can be trivially written as the product of one or many primes

Step: Suppose that for every number $j$ such that $2\leq j\leq k$, $j$ can be written as the product of one or more primes. Then if $k+1$ is prime, it satisfies the property trivially. If $k+1$ is not prime, it is composite, meanining that there is a $1<a<k+1$  such that $a | k+1$.

From $1<a<k+1$  we can infer $2 \leq a<k+1$

Now we can infer that $k+1=ac$, so it can be written as the product of two integers $a$ and $c$

1. Since $k+1 \neq a $ then $c > 1$ so $2 \leq c$.
2. Since $ a > 1 $, $c <k+1$.

So k+1 can be written with two integer numbers, $a$ and $c$ greater than or equal 2 and less than $k+1$, so by inductive hypothesis it ca be written as the product of primes.

Are points 1 and 2 correct?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think , you mean product of primes instead of sum. What exactly is your doubt ?

Comment: If $a$ is a nontrivial factor of $k+1$ (that is $1<a<k+1$) , this is also the case for the cofactor $c$. Hence both $a$ and $c$ are smaller than $k+1$ hence we can apply the induction hypothesis. It does not matter which of $a,c$ is bigger or whether they are equal.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to be more clear on the points I am not sure about

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, should be correct now

Comment: In several places the word "many" should really be "finitely many".

Comment: Yes, the statements (1) and (2) are correct. However the sentence following them makes a jump in the logic that you didn't justify. So far you have only demonstated that $k+1 = ac$ with both $1 < a, c < k+1$. But $a$ and $c$ are not necessarily primes, so you have not yet demonstrated $k+1$ is a product of primes. You have to do one more step for that demonstration.

Comment: @PaulSinclair  Can't we conclude that since a,c are both >= 2 and <k+1, by inductive hypothesis then they belong to the set of integers that can be written as a product of primes?

Comment: Yes, because $a, c \le k$, they can be written as products of primes, and therefore their product is also a product of primes. This is the step you missed. After belaboring earlier details to an inordinate degree, you skipped over this step without mention. Experienced readers will of course be able to fill in those steps, but experienced readers would have no need for this proof at all. Some inexperienced readers would find your conclusion without this explanation very confusing. (Believe me, I've run into a lot of them.)